# JSP kendo grid EDIT /ADD Handle ERROR response from spring rest Kendo UI v2015.3.1111

Tags: spring, rest, jsp, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Trying Kendo UI JSP editable grid. Grid is working with few problems.
(Version : Kendo UI v2015.3.1111 )

1. Export: Even with allPages="allPages", its exporting only current
   page.
2. After CREATE, GRID is not updated with server response which has user      createDate. Same with Update, grid not updated with update date
   even though the updated user object is passed.
3. Grid shows user added even if it failed in the backend. How to handle error response for create /update and show the failed message ?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Controller create part:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody User create(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> model) {
        log.debug("create");
        User target = new User();

        target.setUserName((String)model.get("UserName"));
        target.setFirstName((String)model.get("firstName"));
        target.setLastName((String)model.get("lastName"));
        target.setOpenDate(getDateFromStr((String)model.get("openDate")));
        target.setEditDate(getDateFromStr((String)model.get("editDate")));
        User user = userDao.createUser(target);
        log.info("user"+user.getUserId()+user.getOpenDate());
        return user;
    }
```

JSP PART:

```
<c:url value="/user/create" var="createUrl" />
<c:url value="/user/read" var="readUrl" />
<c:url value="/user/update" var="updateUrl" />
<c:url value="/user/destroy" var="destroyUrl" />
<c:url value="/user/saveexcel" var="saveExcelUrl" />
<c:url value="/user/savepdf" var="savePdfUrl" />
```

```
<kendo:grid name="grid" pageable="true" sortable="true" height="750px" filterable="true">
    <kendo:grid-scrollable/>
    <kendo:grid-pdf fileName="KendoUIGridExport.pdf" allPages="allPages"  proxyURL="${savePdfUrl}"/>
    <kendo:grid-excel fileName="KendoUIGridExport.xlsx"   allPages="allPages" proxyURL="${saveExcelUrl}" />
    <kendo:grid-editable mode="popup" confirmation="Are you sure you want to remove this item?"/>
    <kendo:grid-toolbar>
        <kendo:grid-toolbarItem name="create"/>
        <kendo:grid-toolbarItem name="excel"/>
        <kendo:grid-toolbarItem name="pdf"/>
    </kendo:grid-toolbar>
    <kendo:grid-columns>
        <kendo:grid-column title="User Name" field="userName"  width="120px"/>
        <kendo:grid-column title="First Name" field="firstName" width="120px" />
        <kendo:grid-column title="Last Name" field="lastName" width="120px" />
           <kendo:grid-column title="Open Date" field="openDate" width="120px" format="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"  />              

          <kendo:grid-column title="Edit Date" field="editDate" width="120px" format="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"  />              
        <kendo:grid-column title="&nbsp;" width="150px">
            <kendo:grid-column-command>
                <kendo:grid-column-commandItem name="edit" />
                <kendo:grid-column-commandItem name="destroy" />
            </kendo:grid-column-command>
        </kendo:grid-column>
    </kendo:grid-columns>
    <kendo:dataSource pageSize="10" serverPaging="false" serverSorting="false" serverFiltering="false" serverGrouping="false" >
        <kendo:dataSource-transport>
            <kendo:dataSource-transport-create url="${createUrl}" type="POST"  dataType="json" contentType="application/json"/>
            <kendo:dataSource-transport-read url="${readUrl}"  type="POST" dataType="json" contentType="application/json"/>
            <kendo:dataSource-transport-update url="${updateUrl}"  type="POST" dataType="json" contentType="application/json" />
            <kendo:dataSource-transport-destroy url="${destroyUrl}" type="POST" dataType="json" contentType="application/json" />
            <kendo:dataSource-transport-parameterMap>
                <script>
                    function parameterMap(options,type) {

                        return JSON.stringify(options);                         
                    }
                </script>
            </kendo:dataSource-transport-parameterMap>
        </kendo:dataSource-transport>
        <kendo:dataSource-schema>
            <kendo:dataSource-schema-model id="userId">
                <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-fields>
                    <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name="userName" type="string" >
                        <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field-validation required="true" />
                    </kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field>
                    <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name="firstName" type="string">
                        <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field-validation required="true" />
                    </kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field>
                    <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name="lastName" type="string">
                        <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field-validation required="true" />
                    </kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field>
                        <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name="openDate" type="date" editable="false" />
                      <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name="editDate" type="date" editable="false"/>
                </kendo:dataSource-schema-model-fields>
            </kendo:dataSource-schema-model>
        </kendo:dataSource-schema>
    </kendo:dataSource>
</kendo:grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved myself: For pdf,  allPages="true" works.

Grid refresh: FOR requestEnd event

```
    function onRequestEnd(e) {
      if (e.type == "create") {
            e.sender.read();
      }
      else if (e.type == "update") {
            e.sender.read();
      }
   }
```